# C++ regex: convert C# regex to C++ Linux

Tags: c#, c++, regex, linux

I can I convert exactly this regex in c#:

```
Regex (@"\s*nameserver\s+(?<address>.*)")
Regex (@"\s*search\s+(?<domain>.*)")
```

to std::tr1::regex or to regex.h in C++? (Linux)

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::tr1::regex` in GCC is incompelete. `std::regex` have bugs.

Consider `boost::regex`.

Comment: I can't use boost, do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the std::tr1::regex package, but if it is in fact based on boost::regex, then it should be trivial to translate these regexes:

```
"\\s*nameserver\\s+(?<address>.*)"
"\\s*search\\s+(?<domain>.*)"
```

You need to escape the backslashes when constructing the string that contains the regex. Apart from that, those two regexes don't use any features that boost::regex's Perl-compatible engine can't handle.

Comment: IIRC they are using the boost package for regex http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html

Comment: @Uwe Keim: Thanks for the information! Well in that case, they (at least when using the Perl compatible engine) should even be able to handle named capturing groups. So probably it's the need to escape the backslashes...

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, if you are using, g++, you are out of luck: Regular expressions are currently not implemented in g++/tr1:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.tr1